# Minimum trace distance when using a via fence in a waveguide

Tags: pcb-design, high-speed, routing, waveguide

I am trying to route several high speed JESD204B signals (up to 12GHz) to a connector and there is very small area for them. The [manufacturer design note (p.113)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adrv9009.pdf) recommends to route those signals on an inner layer with GND planes above and below the signals with a via fence. Since each signal is in a waveguide, I was wondering if crosstalk would be an issue or should I be worried about return paths being so close to each other.

If I use:

- microvias diameter=0.25mm, hole diameter=0.1mm
- diff pair width = 0.075mm, separation = 0.175mm, clearance to gnd = 0.075mm
- dialectric H1=H2=0.1143, dialectric constant=4.0

Would I be in trouble?

Example of absolute minimum distance:
[image: Example of absolute minimum distance]

Edit: I noticed that in the image, distance between signals in 0.125mm. It's a mistake. I will use 0.175mm

Comment: If the return planes are close, with that high Ghz signals the return paths are practically following the signal traces. No trouble. Only with the signal via’s, where possible stubs are present and return via’s (gnd) are necessary.

Comment: @RemyHx I'm using microvias so there are no stubs and I'm going to add return vias near signal vias.